# Interaction potential in standard $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525), the authors consider a real scalar field theory in $d$-dimensional flat Minkowski space-time, with the action given by
$$S=\int d^d\! x \left[\frac12(\partial_\mu\phi)^2-U(\phi)\right],$$ 
where $U(x)$ is a general self-interaction potential. Then, the authors proceed by saying that for the standard $\phi^4$ theory, the interaction potential can be written as
$$U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8} \phi^2 (\phi -2)^2.$$

Why is this so? What is the significance of the cubic term present?

**EDIT:
Comparing with the scalar field theory the potential term involved with $\lambda$. What is the value we have inserted here?**

Moreover I want to transform the potential to a new form $$U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8}  \lambda(\phi ^2 -v^2)^2.$$  (I have got this from Mark Srednicki page no 576. )

Comment: Standard $\phi^{4}$ theory doesn't have a cubic term.  Are you trying to set up symmetry breaking?

Comment: your $U(\phi)$ term has a manifest cubic term in it.  If you are doing the trick where you expand around a minimum or something, as in the Higgs mechanism, then you can do a transformation to get a term like you have by making manipulations to the action that don't change the EOM.

Comment: Hi @Forhad_jnu. This question was flagged for being _Not A Real Question,_ so I'm closing it for now. The point being that you would have to import further assumptions about your system to deduce any specific behaviour of the potential $U$.

Comment: arxiv.org/pdf/0802.3525 check the paper in the small amplitude expansion. I think you people sometimes close a  good question without good reasoning.

Comment: @Forhad_jnu, to be clear, QMechanic is not closing it permanently, it is closed so you'll edit it and address the issues that they have mentioned, and if it looks good, they'll reopen. It is just the way things are done here.

Comment: Yep, Thnks@lurscher, I already addressed the article location. I am confused that, why did they choose the interaction potential?

Comment: i had a look at your link. the potential form you have in your question  is under "II. THE SMALL AMPLITUDE EXPANSION". @JerrySchirmer has answered that it could appear in an expansion. Why don't you edit your question and include the archive link so that it may be opened and answered in context. there is an edit button under your question.

Comment: They choose a more familiar form of the action [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0609023v1.pdf) with minima at +/-1.  In your case they have the minima at 0 and 2.  Maybe that's more convenient for their purposes.

Comment: I think everybody avoiding my simple question, I just want to know about interaction potential. Please help me if someone can elaborate the term.,

Comment: And I don't think this question should be closed for more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Oh, I see that this is basically what [twistor59 wrote in a comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52590/interaction-potential-in-standard-phi4-theory/52642#comment106893_52590).

---

Set $\psi = \phi - 1$. The Lagrangian written in terms of $\psi$ is

$$ S = \int |\nabla \psi|^2 + V(\psi) $$

where $V(\psi) = U(\phi) = U(\psi + 1)$, expanding the reparametrization we have

$$ V(\psi) = \frac18 (\psi + 1)^2 (\psi - 1)^2 = \frac18 (\psi^4 - 2 \psi^2 + 1) $$

The constant 1 is not dynamical so the potential is equivalent to

$$ \tilde{V}(\psi) = \frac18 (\psi^4 - 2 \psi^2) $$

which is equivalent to the standard $\psi^4$ potential *without cubic term* up to scaling constants.

That is to say: the $\phi^3$ term isn't really there: it can be gauged away.

Comment: the potential term I wrote, is included $\phi^3$ but you omitted. IS the potential arbitrary to choose?

Comment: $U(\phi) = V(\psi)$ when $\psi = \phi -1$. Just plug it in.

Comment: Got the equation but can you please elaborate re-parametrization?? Did you guess the potential as periodic?

Comment: It is just a standard gauge transformation / change of variables. I really don't see what there is to elaborate (honest!). You graph the potential $U$, you graph the standard $\phi^4$ potential, you notice that the two potentials are exactly the same except for translations. You note that translations do not change the kinetic energy part, and voila!

Comment: Minor notational comment: Scalar field theory does not have gauge symmetry, and in particular, $\phi\to \phi-1$ is _not_ a gauge transformation.

Comment: @Qmechanic: yes yes, I welcome suggestions on other colloquial names for "change of coordinate system on the target manifold".

Comment: @WillieWong "Field redefinition" seems to be the standard term.

Comment: @ Willie Wong, Can you check the edit please?

Comment: @QFT: you may want to post that as a more fleshed out separate follow up question. I don't have Srednicki, and I don't understand what you are asking in your edit.