# Derivation of master equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)* I want to get the Equation(9) with comparing the equation (2). Please elaborate the left side of equation (9).

**Small amplitude quasi-breathers and oscillons* by G. Fodor, et al.
arXiv:0802.3525.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52590/2451

Comment: It would be good if  OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation (v3) self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Comment: You can open the article from the given link to see  details.

Comment: A reader should be able to tell whether the question is interesting to him, or not, _before_ he has to click any links. In general, the pleasure and usefulness of browsing Phys.SE greatly diminish if one has to open documents to decide which content to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the left side of eqn. (2):

$-\phi_{t,t,}(x,t)+\Delta\phi(x,t)$

Since this should be a non linear wave equation, $\phi_{t,t}$ means the second derivation in time of $\phi$. Now we make a variable change. First, set $\zeta^i/\varepsilon= x^i$ (eqn. (6)). We put that into $\Delta=\sum\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$, which yields $\Delta=\varepsilon^2\sum\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \zeta_i^2}\equiv\tilde{\Delta}$.

Now make the second variable change: $\tau/\omega(\varepsilon)=t$ (eqn.(7)). Compute the second derivation in time as needed: $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}=[\omega(\epsilon)]^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2}$.

Our function will change from $\phi(x,t) \to \phi(\zeta,\tau)$. Plug the transformed operators into the left side as well and we get:

$-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\phi(x,t)+\Delta\phi(x,t)=-[\omega(\epsilon)]^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2}\phi(\zeta,\tau)+\epsilon^2\tilde{\Delta}\phi(\zeta,\tau)$

This is now the left side of eqn. (9). They only renamed the operators again and left away the dependencies:

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2}\phi(\zeta,\tau)=\ddot{\phi} \qquad \tilde{\Delta}=\Delta$

I hope this makes it clear for you.

**EDIT: Additional question**

Ok. How to gain eqns. (10-12). Write down the $\varepsilon$-expansions for $\omega$ and $\phi$ up to third order in $\varepsilon$ (eqns. (5) and (8)):

$\omega^2=1+\sum\varepsilon^k \omega_k=1+\varepsilon\omega_1+\varepsilon^2\omega_2+\varepsilon^3\omega_3+\dots$

$\phi=\sum\varepsilon^k \phi_k=\varepsilon\phi_1+\varepsilon^2\phi_2+\varepsilon^3\phi_3+\dots$

Take the derivatives on $\phi$ which you need according to eqn. (9) and put everything together:

$-[1+\varepsilon\omega_1+\varepsilon^2\omega_2+\varepsilon^3\omega_3][\varepsilon\ddot\phi_1+\varepsilon^2\ddot\phi_2+\varepsilon^3\ddot\phi_3] = \varepsilon\phi_1+\varepsilon^2\phi_2+\varepsilon^3\phi_3 + \sum g_k\phi^k$

I will show you what is the principle and derive eqn. (10). You'll have to do the rest by your own. We now search for the **first order solution**. That means we will only recognize that part of the equation where we find the first order of $\varepsilon$ and we will throw everything else away. Means, for first order only write down what has a $\varepsilon^1$, for the second order you will have to write down everything with a $\varepsilon^2$. On the right side you will get only $\varepsilon \phi_1$ since everything else is higher order in $\epsilon$ except the sum, which is zero order. On the left side you will maintain only $-\varepsilon\ddot\phi_1$ since everything else is of higher order. So we ended up with

$-\varepsilon\ddot\phi_1=\varepsilon \phi_1 \Leftrightarrow \ddot\phi_1+\phi_1=0$

which is eqn. (10).

Comment: Thnx you have done great.

Comment: Thanks. Ca you please look after little bit on the equation (10)

Comment: Was my edit that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thnx got it :-) you wrote explicitly understandable. I checked your contact info but there was none. Can I be added with you?

Comment: As far as I know, this site is not intended to connect it's members.

Comment: Can you check the equation(11)? The equation doesn't have any $\Delta \phi$ term  and in equation (12), i see a term $2 g_2 \phi_1 \phi_2$. how these term arise?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52753/solution-of-inhomogeneous-equation can you check the question?

Comment: Your last question, I answered in the new post. For the one before: Be careful! The right side contains a $\sum g_k \phi^k$. That $\phi$ under the sum has to be expanded as well! That is the point where the $g_k$-terms arise.

Comment: Ok I'm trying then.

Comment: If the equation(11) comparison the coefficient of $\epsilon^2$ then how they ignored  $\Delta \phi $ in the equation (11).

Comment: Look at the definitions: The lowest order in $\phi$ is $\varepsilon^1$, in front of $\Delta$ there is $\varepsilon^2$, so the lowest order of $\varepsilon^2\Delta\phi$ will be $\varepsilon^3$.

Comment: got it. in equation(12) $2g_2 \phi_1 \phi_2$ term combined $ \phi_1 \phi_2$ but there is no term to multiply.

Comment: What would be the expansion of $g_k \phi^k$? 
Is it $g_k \phi^k = g_1 \phi^1+ g_2 \phi^2 + g_3 \phi^3 + g_4 \phi^4....$ or epsilon term needed to add. If need then how to?

Comment: can you please have a look in this problem http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54864/problem-in-comparing-coefficients?