# Scalar field lagrangian and potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

This question is a continuation of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52590/2451) Phys.SE post.

Scalar field theory does not have gauge symmetry, and in particular, $\phi\to\phi−1$ is not a gauge transformation. but why?
and

**I want see the mathematics that will represent the interaction potential from the Lagrangian for scalar field.**

Details in the paper: [see check the equation (3) please.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no physical redundancy in the description. A gauge theory (and related gauge transformations) only occurs if there are different field configurations corresponding to a certain physical configuration. Such redundant configurations can be related by local gauge transformations (see for example the vector potential $A_\mu$ in electrodynamics). In your case (which the other question referred to), the Lagrangian is not invariant under your transformation, since the quantity 
$$U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8} \phi^2 (\phi -2)^2$$
changes under $\phi\rightarrow\phi-1$ to

$$U(\phi-1)= \frac{1}{8} (\phi-1)^2 (\phi -3)^2.$$

Comment: Where from the equation $U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8} \phi^2 (\phi -2)^2$  arises or more precisely why did we write in this form?

Comment: That's the interaction potential you wrote down in your other question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52590/interaction-potential-in-standard-phi4-theory

Comment: My curiosity is why did he write the equation like this?

Comment: Such a term (i.e. one of a higher order than 2) is necessary in order to get interactions in your theory.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525 
in this article, check the equation(3) please.

Comment: What you see there is the aforementioned potential and its derivative with respect to the field.

Comment: I need a  source  where from they wrote the equation.

Comment: Interaction terms like those are treated by introductory QFT books like Peskin and Schroeder or Srednicki.

Comment: Hi Frederic, your analysis is correct but of course there's something fishy going on with the Lagrangian: they've rescaled $\phi$ by some energy scale (of the order of the vev) but haven't corrected the kinetic terms. (Unless $D = 2$ of course.) Maybe you can mention this, I don't have time right now to do things carefully.

Comment: @Vibert Sorry, I don't see what you mean. Could you please point me to the expression you are referring to?

Comment: @FredericBrünner: a scalar field has (mass) dimension $(d-2)/2$, so an expression like $(\phi - 2)^2$ can only be meaningful when $\phi$ is rescaled by some dimensionful parameter $v$. The Lagrangian I'm referring to is the one in the original post (the first link in OP's post), which has a canonically normalized kinetic term.

Comment: @Vibert You are correct, thanks for pointing this out!