# Interaction potential analysis from $\phi^4$ model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, field-theory

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525), the authors consider a real scalar field theory in $d$-dimensional flat Minkowski space-time, with the action given by
$$S=\int d^d\! x \left[\frac12(\partial_\mu\phi)^2-U(\phi)\right],$$ 
where $U(x)$ is a general self-interaction potential. Then, the authors proceed by saying that for the standard $\phi^4$ theory, the interaction potential can be written as
$$U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8} \phi^2 (\phi -2)^2.$$

Why is this so? What is the significance of the cubic term present?

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52590/interaction-potential-in-standard-phi4-theory) Willie Wong  answered by setting $\psi = \phi - 1$, why is that? Or why is this a gauge transformation?
Does anyone have better argument to understand the interection potential?

Comment: It's a field redefinition. You can use this $\psi$ in your calculations and if necessary switch back to $\phi$ in the end, if you need to. In other words, knowing the correlation functions $\langle \phi(x_1) \dotsm \phi(x_n) \rangle$ is completely equivalent to knowing $\langle \psi(x_1) \dotsm \psi(x_n) \rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a gauge transformation, it's a *field redefinition*.  [Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) gives an example of this in exercise 10.5.  In this exercise, a free field theory is turned into what looks like an interacting field theory by a field redefinition, however in perturbation theory, the scattering amplitudes vanish, confirming that the physics hasn't changed.

I suspect you will find the same here (though I haven't done it!) - if you compute scattering amplitudes for the 3-way vertices represented by the cubic terms resulting from this field redefinition, they should cancel.

Comment: That's precisely what I meant with my comment above.

Comment: @Vibert  Oh yes, I think we posted simultaneously!

Comment: Twistor, i got the problem 10.5. can you please  redefine this field so i will have more clear understanding.

Comment: @QFTdreamer I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  All I'm saying is that your $\phi \rightarrow \phi-1$ is analogous to Srednicki's $\phi \rightarrow \phi+\lambda\phi^2$.

Comment: How will I confirm that my redefination is correct?

Comment: @QFTdreamer Like in the Srednicki problem you could start by computing the tree level amplitudes and show that the three-point vertex contributions cancel.

Comment: Or is there any way to validate the redefination?

Comment: Can you show me that please? then I will have clear understanding.

Comment: @QFTdreamer I would say that is a separate question.  I'm not sure that asking for drill type questions like that is appropriate for phyiscs.se, but you could try, to see what response you get.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to find out that.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55532/how-the-nonlinear-equation-can-be-written-like-this. can you check this question pleaee?

Comment: A field redefinition cannot be 'correct' or 'wrong'. At this point, it's just bookkeeping. But you can interpret the resulting Lagrangian. If you get a positive mass term and a positive $\phi^4$ coupling, then you have a physical boson with quartic self-interactions. If you get a negative mass term, there will be SSB (as usual) and you should think of the field as "vev + excitations". However, _formally_ the two theories are equal.