# How the nonlinear equation can be written like this?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

We consider a scalar theory in a $1+D$ dimensional flat Minkowski
space-time, with a general self-interaction
potential, whose action can be written as
\begin{equation}
A=\int dt\, d^D\! x \left[\frac12(\partial_t\phi)^2-\frac12(\partial_i\phi)^2
-U(\phi)\right] \,,
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is a real scalar field, $\partial_t=\partial/\partial t$,
$\partial_i=\partial/\partial x^i$ and $i=1,2,\ldots,D$.
The equation of motion following from \eqref{action}
is a non-linear wave equation (NLWE) which is given as
$$
 -\phi_{,tt} + \Delta \phi = U'(\phi)=\phi +\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}g_k\phi^k \tag{1}$$
 where $$\quad{\Delta}=\sum_{i=1}^{D}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}\,.
$$
I just want to know the logic, that how they transformed the equation (1)

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54931/2451

Answer (score 1):

They just expanded the "potential" derivative $U'(\phi)$ in a Taylor series in powers of $\phi$. Kind of polynomial self-interaction.

The coefficient $g_1$ can always be made to be unity with help of redefinition of $t$ and $x$, so they wrote $g_1=1$.