# $\phi ^4$ theory explaining

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

In  $φ^4$ theory we often write the Lagrangian as  $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4 \tag {1}$$

If I want to write from the Relativistic Lagrangian then it takes $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -V \tag{2}$$
but how will I convert this equation to equation like (1) ?

EDIT: I just want to get Equation (1) from equation (2)

EDIT by joshphysics: What motivates choosing to study the $\phi^4$ potential as opposed to other potentials?

Comment: what does 'write down from the source' mean?

Comment: Are you asking why the potential is chosen to be of that form in the sense of what do we gain by studying the $\phi$-fourth potential?

Comment: Yup , mathematical details will be good for me :)

Comment: @nervxxx , I just want to get Equation (1) from equation (2)

Comment: if you just want to get (1) from (2) then er... set $V = \frac{m}{2} \phi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4$......? I don't really know what you're trying to ask.

Comment: That's the point , I just need to know, why did we put the potential you wrote. Didn't  it disturb the equation?

Comment: Related questions by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52590/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Looks like your question isn't quite clear; you may want to elaborate. I'll close it for now, flag it once you have elaborated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, you would like to know why we often choose to study the special potential
$$
  V(\phi) = \frac{1}{2} m\phi^2 + \frac{1}{4!}\lambda \phi^4
$$
Here are a couple of reasons

1. It yields a simple example of an *interacting* field theory.  If you were to have chosen $V(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}m\phi^2$, then the corresponding Lagrangian is that of a *free* (non-interacting) massive scalar of mass $m$, and we want to go beyond free theory.
2. It's one of the simplest local functions of $\phi$ you can write down that gives you interactions since it's just a polynomial in $\phi$.  Why not $\phi^3$?  Well you can really just as well pick $\phi^3$ and learn a lot about how scalar field theory works (as in Srednicki), but people like using the $\phi^4$ potential because it is bounded below and doesn't have an unstable critical point at the origin like the $\phi^3$ potential does.

Comment: So, I can transform the potential to $U(\phi)= \frac{1}{8} \phi^2 (\phi -2)^2$ ? If yes then how?

Comment: More details on http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52590/interaction-potential-in-standard-phi4-theory