# A fundamental equation for solitary wave and dimension analysis

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

According to the scalar Field theory we write Lagrangian as  $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4 \tag {1}$$
What I want to do is to get a equation of solitary wave (solition) from the above Lagrangian which will lead for solving many solitary problems like life-time, dimension analysis etc.
My confusion is choosing the potential because it may vary and depend on the author's selection. What are the physical constraints on choosing an appropriate potential?
Another rather technical expectation is solitary wave is nonlinear equation so how will I write down the equation as 2nd order differential equation with respect to time?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60915/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have made the question a bit more conceptual and distinced it from the more conceptual part. I think with my edits, it is now a valid and legitimate question. Can it be reopend?

Comment: @Dilaton   This is still a bad question.  I don't think small perturbations will salvage it.

Comment: @user1504 I dont see why you say it is still a bad question. In addition, in view of the increased dominance of homework and very low-level questions from people who have almost no physics knowledge of their own, it is particularly bad that (technical) questions about slightly more advanced and/or more fundamental topics can never be reopend when they are closed once.

Comment: It simply doesn't matter that the question is about sophisticated math, when it simply requests to be given a finished product without any sign the asker has put any effort into the problem to start with or understands the basics of how solitary waves work.

Comment: @dmckee to me it looks very much pointless now to improve non-homework or non-very-basic questions and try to get them reopend because it NEVER EVER works. For example why the hell is it not valid to ask about the physics determining the potential to obtain a soliton equation? Only homework questions get reopend, after the OP has put in his own effort and very basic high school ones. It is very frustrating that slightly higher level questions get never reopend once closed, whatever one does.

Comment: @dmckee Manishearth has suggested to edit closed questions and flag them for reopen. Getting every single flag to reopen declined however looks lick flagging to reopen perse is discuraged, at least by the flag handling moderator. So could this flags not be considered helpful to encourage more people to flag to reopen (I am actually the only one who does and much more people should get involved in salvagable questions)?. But maybe I should give up all efforts in this direction too, because it is completely pointless. Non-basic questions are dead, as soon as they get closed and nothing helps!

Comment: @Dilaton I think you may have failed to grasp why this question was closed in the first place. I have to guess at that, as I  decided I wasn't sufficiently sure to close it on my own, but the text didn't suggest to me that the author had done any thinking about or looking at basic references on their own. Your edit didn't change that. This still looks like a more sophisticated version of *"Give me the formula to solve my homework"*. Editing to improve the question is a great idea, but you have to *improve* the question for it to help.

Comment: @dmckee so is guessing what the OP wanted and make the make (possible) physics questions contained in the post no improvement? I think the attitude of the reader of a question plays a not unimportant rule whene determining the merit of a question. You (and others) say it is still a gimme the eqn question, but I say  when asking it like it is now, it is very probable that answeres give not just the equation but physics explanations why a particular potential is needed to lead to soliton solutions too. Many people do not try to find the good in any question and anticipate the good answers it

Comment: could attract, of one lets it get answered (!) as I do it. For example I tried often to get quetions David has closed (on his own) reopend after edit, but we ofte just talk past each other, because he constantly refuses to consider my more positive way of looking at the merits of a question and its possible answers :-(.