# value of $\omega$ in nonlinear equation

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, non-linear-systems

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525) the authors wrote a nonlinear equation as 
$$-\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}+ \nabla \phi= \phi+ \sum_{k=2}^\infty g_k \phi^k$$

They have scaled the time as,
$$\tau=\omega(\varepsilon) t$$
where they argued that $\omega$ is analytic near the threshold value, $\omega = 1$.  Later they argue that $\omega_{1} = 0$ because they are looking for bounded solutions.  They argue this is equivalent to a lack of the resonance term $\omega_{1} \ddot{\phi}_{1}$ in their equation (11).

Can anyone provide a justification for these two assumptions and why these assumptions are valid?

Comment: Related question which also links to arXiv:0802.3525: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52590/2451 and links therein.