# Is the exact form of the Higgs potential known?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, higgs

Usually the Higgs potential is given as $$ \frac{1}{2}\mu^2\phi^2 - \frac{1}{4}\lambda^2\phi^4 $$ but I never quite understood if this just serves to give us an idea of how symmetry breaking works, or if it is actually the *correct* expression for the potential.

Does the potential above agree with experiments? Is that the Higgs potential?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is the Higgs potential of the Standard Model.

Note that a $\phi^3$ term is forbidden by symmetry (it would not be an $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ scalar), and $\mathcal{O}(\phi^5)$ terms would be non-renormalizable, so this is really the only potential we can write down that does not need other new physics.

Comment: but the effective potential can look a bit different a la Coleman-Weinberg

Comment: Is there an easy/intuitive way of understanding why the $\mathcal{O}(\phi^5)$ term in non-renormalisable?

Comment: @SuperCiocia: If you know the power-counting renormalizability argument, it's obvious from the mass dimension the coupling must have for terms of order higher than 4, if not, then not.

Comment: And why is the $\phi$ term at power one is forbidden ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian 1. It would also not be a scalar. 2. Linear terms [can be transformed away](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103328/50583) anyway.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : thank you

Comment: Is there any reason a $(\Psi \Psi^*)^{-2}$ term can't be present (renormalizable) perhaps with an additive constant to bound it?